# Git differences between git show and git diff

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I found quite strange issue. I have repo hosted on Bitbucket. Once I've commited some files but on Bitbucket it's only 1 file visible in this commit to be updated.

I've verified it on localhost and when I run:

```
git show 09fd1be7ab54253aaf79ca58f17dd2b07effbf22
```

I see only 1 file modified (same as on Bitbucket).

However when I compare this commit with previous one using:

```
git diff --name-only 092fd26 09fd1be
```

I'm getting this file and 5 more. Also in my IDE (PhpStorm) I also see those 5 files difference between commits.

How could it be? The strangest issue is that when I pushed this commit, after a few days my colleague did the same as I did in this commit because he said those changes were not visible in repository.

Comment: There's more information needed. Are the two commits you're comparing, `092fd26` and `09fd1be`, directly next to each other in history? Which version of information is correct? Did you edit five files and include them in the commit you're trying to look at with `git show 09fd1be`? Or, did you only edit one file between `092fd26` and `09fd1be`?

Comment: Yes, those commits are directly after each other and as far as I remember (it happened about a month ago) I've commited all the files but I'm not sure if it was in this commit

Comment: You can see if those commits are directly after each other with `git log`. I suggest using [specific options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) with `git log` to find out the accurate information of history, then comparing it to the two commit SHA1 hash IDs to see where the discrepancy is occurring.

Comment: @BrianaSwift Could you please tell more? If I run `git log` (what I already verified earlier) I have those 2 commits one after each other but I don't know what more should I also compare

Comment: Is this commit `09fd1be` a _merge_ commit ? I do recall different behavior of `git show` in merge commits.

Comment: Is this commit `09fd1be` a _merge_ commit ? I do recall different behavior of `git show` in merge commits.

Comment: @ChananelP No, it's not but the next one is merge commit and the only visible file in this merge is the only one showed in `git show`

Comment: What does `git diff 092fd26 09fd1be` show? Are there still 5 files? What kind of changes are there which are missed from `git show`?

Comment: @max630 as I've mentioned `git diff --name-only` (and the same `git diff`) show 5 files changed, only `git show` shows 1 file modified